# Picasa iFrame Slideshow

Tags: iframe, joomla, slideshow, google-plus, picasa

Is there an iFrame slideshow to show a Picasa Album? I'm running Joomla! so an iFrame is a whole lot easier to work with. Any ideas? If you could do Google+ albums instead that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You can use [Picasa Webalbum Integrator](http://code.google.com/p/pwi/) for your requirement.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link   href="css/pwi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.pwi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#container").pwi({
                username: 'tester'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

or something like,

```
<IFRAME SRC="(album link)#slideshow" WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=600 SCROLLING=NO>
</IFRAME>
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Joomla also has an API for Picasa so you can easily write a plugin using that, assuming this is a programming question :).